# - copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTimeForDisplay: null value

Tags: ios9, avasset, avplayeritem, cvpixelbuffer

The issue I have is when I compile my app with iOS9 sdk when my app try to get a `CVPixelBufferRef` from an `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` with the `- copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTimeForDisplay:` function I get a null value from time to time when the video is loaded and all the instances are created.

with iOS 8 my app was working fine, but with iOS9 is giving me the issue, even the version of my app that is in the app store available for download that was compiled with iOS 8 SDK is giving me the same problem when is installed in IOS9.

When the  problem happens and I get a null `getCVPixelBufferRef`, if I press the home button and the app goes to background when I open the app again and becomes active the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` instance that was giving me the null `CVPixelBufferRef` starts to work fine and the issue is solved.

Here is a youtube video where I replicate the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=997zG08_DMM&feature=youtu.be

Here is the sample code in order to create the instances of all the items:

```
NSURL *url ;
url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[_mainVideo objectForKey:@"file"]];

NSDictionary *pixBuffAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)};
_videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:pixBuffAttributes];
_myVideoOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myVideoOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[_videoOutput setDelegate:self queue:_myVideoOutputQueue];

_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];


// Do not take mute button into account
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                error:&error];
if (!success) {
   // NSLog(@"Could not use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback", nil);
}

asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];


if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[asset URL] path]]) {
   // NSLog(@"file does not exist");
}

NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:^{

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       /* Make sure that the value of each key has loaded successfully. */
                       for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys)
                       {
                           NSError *error = nil;
                           AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];
                           if (keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed)
                           {
                               [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback:error];
                               return;
                           }
                       }

                       NSError* error = nil;
                       AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:kTracksKey error:&error];
                       if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
                       {
                           //_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];


                           [_playerItem addOutput:_videoOutput];
                           [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
                           [_videoOutput requestNotificationOfMediaDataChangeWithAdvanceInterval:ONE_FRAME_DURATION];

                           /* When the player item has played to its end time we'll toggle
                            the movie controller Pause button to be the Play button */
                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                    selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                                        name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                      object:_playerItem];

                           seekToZeroBeforePlay = NO;

                           [_playerItem addObserver:self
                                         forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                                            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                            context:AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext];

                           [_player addObserver:self
                                     forKeyPath:kCurrentItemKey
                                        options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                        context:AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerCurrentItemObservationContext];

                           [_player addObserver:self
                                     forKeyPath:kRateKey
                                        options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                        context:AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerRateObservationContext];


                           [self initScrubberTimer];

                           [self syncScrubber];


                       }
                       else
                       {
                         //  NSLog(@"%@ Failed to load the tracks.", self);
                       }
                   });
}];
```

Heres the sample code giving me the null pixel buffer

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer =
[_videoOutput
 copyPixelBufferForItemTime:[_playerItem currentTime]
itemTimeForDisplay:nil];

NSLog(@"the pixel buffer is %@", pixelBuffer);
NSLog (@"the _videoOutput is %@", _videoOutput.description);
CMTime dataTime = [_playerItem currentTime];
//NSLog(@"the current time is %f", dataTime);
return pixelBuffer;
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?  I built a Unity Plugin for OSX/iOS using similar code and had the same issue.  I have a hack that works for me, but I wouldn't call it a solution so I did not put it as an answer and I am still looking for a more elegant approach.

*** I have found that the allocation of AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc is relative to the format setting you pass to it, but the time it takes is not absolute.  A forced one second wait time between the alloc and loading/playing fixed it for me.  Also I only create 1 AVPlayerItemVideoOutput and reuse it so I only need 1 delay

Comment: I also wanted to note that I have a hard time believing TimoRozendal's answer, because in my case this is not an iOS specific issue, but rather an AVFoundation issue as it also happens on OSX.

Comment: hi @BrianHodge thanks a lot for the hack it really worked, since two months ago I filled a bug report with apple but they are not giving me any feedback, also I requested a support ticket with my developer account    and the guy from apple support told me that they are still trying to find out what is going on so he would not be able to give me a solution or al least a workaround.

Comment: For me it always fails with quicktime video, and work fine with mp4. It might be due to my videoOutput settings

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found the answer in this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27589#128476

You have to wait for the video to be ready to play before adding the output, else it will fail and return nil. My swift code looks like:

```
func retrievePixelBufferToDraw() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  guard let videoItem = player.currentItem else { return nil }
  if videoOutput == nil || self.videoItem !== videoItem {
    videoItem.outputs.flatMap({ return $0 as? AVPlayerItemVideoOutput }).forEach {
      videoItem.remove($0)
    }
    if videoItem.status != AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {
      // see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27589#128476
      return nil
    }

    let pixelBuffAttributes = [
      kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
      ] as [String: Any]

    let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.init(pixelBufferAttributes: pixelBuffAttributes)
    videoItem.add(videoOutput)
    self.videoOutput = videoOutput
    self.videoItem = videoItem
  }
  guard let videoOutput = videoOutput else { return nil }

  let time = videoItem.currentTime()
  if !videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time) { return nil }
  return videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time, itemTimeForDisplay: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a real solution to the problem –which according to your comment seems to be a bug in AVFoundation– I found the better workaround than to wait for 1 second as Brian Hodge suggested, is to recreate the AVPlayer if it fails to deliver pixel buffers. Depending on what your actual restarting routine does this might prove to be significantly faster and less irritating to the user. Also, it introduces a (slight) delay only if the AVPlayer actually had a problem and not everytime you started it.

However, an AVPlayerItemVideoOutput will not deliver any more pixel buffers after the player finished playback. So you probably should guard against that case by remembering if you already received any pixel buffers. Otherwise your player would perform an involuntary loop playback.

**In the class interface:**

```c
@property (nonatomic) BOOL videoOutputHadPixelBuffer;
```

**And then before you try to copy the pixel buffer:**

```c
if (![self.videoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:self.player.currentTime] && !self.videoOutputHadPixelBuffer)
{
    [self restartPlayer]; // call your custom restart routine where you create a new AVPlayer object
}

self.videoOutputHadPixelBuffer = YES; // guard against missing pixel buffers after playback finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and found out that it only happens with:
64 bit devices running ios 9.0 or higher when the project is not built for the `arm64` architecture.

Changing the build settings to build for the `arm64`  architecture solved this issue for me.

Comment: hello here you can find the build settings I have on my app, and arm64 is included since the begining. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnmaqv0i9uycbqo/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-10-28%20a%20las%2011.44.26.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

*Since you said it also worked for you, I decided to post this as an answer, rather than a comment, to give it the most visibility possible.

**Answer:**
I am still looking for a more elegant approach.  I have found that the allocation of AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc is relative to the format setting you pass to it, but the time it takes is not absolute. A forced one second wait time between the alloc and loading/playing fixed it for me. Also I only create 1 AVPlayerItemVideoOutput and reuse it so I only need 1 delay.

**Also:**

Use **hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime** below is a small sample from a unity plugin I made which merely uploads the contents of the pixel buffer to texture.

```
//////////////////////
 if (g_TexturePointer)
{
    if([plug.playerOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:[plug.player currentTime]])
    {
        pbuffer = [plug.playerOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:plug.player.currentItem.currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
    } ... .. . (No need to show the rest.)
```

Happy Coding!